# Laptop battery level monitor for Linux

Tags: beginner, linux, rust, status-monitoring

I come from a C background and am trying to learn Rust. I wrote my first Rust program, to check the battery level on my laptop and warn me if it's low/critical.

It works fine, but I  wrote it in a way I'm familiar with and was wondering if I'm missing out on some features of the Rust language that could make this more portable, more optimal, or safer.

```
extern crate notify_rust;    
use notify_rust::Notification;
use notify_rust::NotificationUrgency;

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

static CHARGE_NOW: &str =  "/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now";
static CHARGE_FULL: &str = "/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full";
static STATUS: &str = "/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status";
static CHARGING_STR: &str = "Charging";

const CHARGE_WARN: f32 = 15.0;
const CHARGE_CRIT: f32 = 5.0;
const NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT: i32 = 4000;

fn main() {

    /* If we're charging, just exit */
    if get_str_from_file(STATUS).trim() == CHARGING_STR {
        std::process::exit(0);
    }

    let charge_level: f32 = (get_float_from_file(CHARGE_NOW) /
                             get_float_from_file(CHARGE_FULL)) * 100.0;

    if charge_level < CHARGE_WARN {
        Notification::new()
            .summary("Battery level low!")
            .body(&format!("Battery level: {0:.1$}%", charge_level, 2))
            .icon("dialog-information")
            .urgency(
                if charge_level < CHARGE_CRIT { 
                    NotificationUrgency::Critical
                } else { 
                    NotificationUrgency::Normal
                }
            )
            .timeout(NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT)
            .show().unwrap();
    }
}

fn get_str_from_file(file_path: &str) -> String {
    let mut file = File::open(file_path)
        .expect("file not found");
    let mut ret = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut ret)
        .expect("failed to read file");

    ret
}

fn get_float_from_file(file_path: &str) -> f32 {
    get_str_from_file(file_path).trim().parse::<f32>().unwrap()
}
```

Used crate: [notify_rust](https://docs.rs/notify-rust/3.4.2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/notify_rust/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unwrapping options is probably fine for this simple little app that only you’re using, but it dumps out a panic if the result is `None`. I like your use of `expect` better. That can give a nicer error message to the user. Either way, it’d be good to learn the more idiomatic way of dealing with options.

```
match x {
    None => foo,
    Some => bar
}
```

The function at the end of your file should probably be returning an `Option` that can be handled in your main logic.

Answer (score 7):

You could replace your `get_str_from_file` function with the standard [`read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_to_string.html) function:

For instance like so:

```
use std::fs;

if fs::read_to_string(STATUS).unwrap().trim() == CHARGING_STR) {
    return; //return should be equivalent to std::process::exit(0)
}
```

This is your implementation:

```
fn get_str_from_file(file_path: &str) -> String {
    let mut file = File::open(file_path)
        .expect("file not found");
    let mut ret = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut ret)
        .expect("failed to read file");

    ret
}
```

This is the implementation of [std::fs::read_to_string](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/fs.rs.html#307-312)

```
pub fn read_to_string<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> io::Result<String> {
    let mut file = File::open(path)?;
    let mut string = String::with_capacity(initial_buffer_size(&file));
    file.read_to_string(&mut string)?;
    Ok(string)
}
```

Almost identical, except the std lib version is more generic and leaves error handling to the caller. It also uses more efficient memory allocation.

#### New Type Idiom

The following is not necessarily better, but it is certainly a valid alternative approach.
Instead of relying on using an `f32` you could use a wrapper struct around it:

```
#[derive(Debug, Default, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, PartialOrd)] //not necessary but nice to have
struct ChargeLevel(f32);
```

This is called [New Type Idiom](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/new_types.html). You could further go ahead and put most of the logic surrounding the charge level into special functions in the `ChargeLevel`'s `impl` block. Some suggestions:

```
impl ChargeLevel {
    const WARNING_LEVEL: f32 = 15.0;
    const CRITICAL_LEVEL: f32 = 5.0;

    fn new(now: f32, full: f32) -> Self {
        ChargeLevel((now / full) * 100.0)
    }

    fn is_warning(&self) -> bool {
        self.0 < Self::WARNING_LEVEL
    }

    fn is_critical(&self) -> bool {
        self.0 < Self::CRITICAL_LEVEL
    }
}
```

You could also combine this struct with the external library stuff:

```
impl From<ChargeLevel> for NotificationUrgency {
    fn from(level: ChargeLevel) -> Self {
        if level.is_critical() {
            NotificationUrgency::Critical
        } else {
            NotificationUrgency::Normal
        }
    }
}
```

This would allow you to replace

```
if charge_level < CHARGE_WARN {
    Notification::new()
        .summary("Battery level low!")
        .body(&format!("Battery level: {0:.1$}%", charge_level, 2))
        .icon("dialog-information")
        .urgency(
            if charge_level < CHARGE_CRIT { 
                NotificationUrgency::Critical
            } else { 
                NotificationUrgency::Normal
            }
        )
        .timeout(NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT)
        .show().unwrap();
}
```

with

```
if charge_level.is_warning() {
    Notification::new()
        .summary("Battery level low!")
        .body(&format!("Battery level: {0:.1$}%", charge_level.0, 2))
        .icon("dialog-information")
        .urgency(NotificationUrgency::from(charge_level))
        .timeout(NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT)
        .show()
        .unwrap();
}
```

A little much for such a small application perhaps, but might give you an example how to write nice abstractions in Rust that don't cost any runtime overhead.

Implementing `std::fmt::Display` would also make sense for the string formatting, but you get the point.